# javascript document.getElementById not working from db

Tags: javascript, html, db2

I'm sure I'm missing something silly here, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I am basically trying to get the names from my database, which is working fine (I can show them on screen), but when I try to get them and store them in a variable, it doesn't work.

here's the code:

```
<% if(data.length){ 
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
    <p id="names"><%= data[i].FULLNAME %></p>
    <% }
           }else{ %>
        <p>nothing</p>
    <% } %>
  <script>
      var listOfNames = document.getElementById("names").value
      console.log("list of names" + listOfNames)
```

I now need a new line after every name, instead of beside each other one by one, like so:
[image]

thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: "names" implies multiple results but getElementById() is used to retrieve a single value.  Why don't you put your result in variable instead of querying them indirectly via the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `innerText` instead of `value`

```js
const listOfNames = document.getElementById("names").value
console.log("list of names: " + listOfNames)

const correctText = document.getElementById("names").innerText
console.log("list of names: " + correctText)
```

```html
<p id="names">whatever</p>
```

Comment: Please accept my solution if it helped you :)

Comment: do you know how I could split the results into a new line? so instead of `name1, name2, name3`, it goes `name1 (newline), name2 (newline), name3 (newline)`

Comment: Use "\n" inside of your text http://jennifermadden.com/javascript/lineBreaks.html#:~:text=The%20Newline%20Character%20%5Cn,text%20or%20JavaScript%2Dgenerated%20HTML.

Comment: that doesn't work. Basically what I'm trying to do is live display and filter the values from the db in a search bar. so when I actually display these results, it still displays one after the other instead of one below the other. not sure if that makes sense

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you are trying to display text in several lines, you need to create several tags, for example paragraphs, HTML tags I mean. Simple text breaks won't work

Comment: i've edited my post to explain more. please let me know if you need more information.